# Any ideas on why tkinter is not running ? Is there an alternative I could use to produce the same result

Tags: python, tkinter, libraries, clock

[VsCode Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfVoc.png) I saw a tutorial for a digital clock on TikTok using the tkinter library but it is not working as you can see by the output of my viscose debugger. What should I use instead ?

I tried adding the deprecation command like they asked, but it was still unsuccessful. What should I do instead ?

Comment: If you have a question or a problem with your code, it's best to provide the code itself instead of a photo of the code. this makes it easier for others to read and understand your code so that they can help you better.

Comment: Don't use the system version of tkinter. Install python with homebrew or from python.org.